# BSON Serialized object can't be deserialized after structural changes

Tags: .net, serialization, json.net, bson

In my project currently (a web application), the user deals with large objects which are serialized into BSON and stored in a database when not in active use. Recently, I made structural changes to this object's class, and this has caused failures in deserialization, throwing the following exception:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Could not find type "....ResultSliceDouble" in assembly...
```

Previously, the class contained multiple instances of two classes, `ResultSliceInt` and `ResultSliceDouble`. Following some refactoring, I renamed `ResultSliceDouble` to `ResultSlice`, deleted the `ResultSliceInt` class, and converted all its instances to use `ResultSlice` instead.

Predictably, if I rename `ResultSlice` back to `ResultSliceDouble`, I get the same exception, but this time about `ResultSliceInt`.

Is there a way that I can safely convert old instances of the class into the new? Invalidating the existing instances altogether is not acceptable as the web application is currently in use by multiple users.

For reference, here is the deserialization code:

```
public static LargeObject DeserializeLargeObject(byte[] objectData)
    {
        var serializer = new JsonSerializer
        {
            ConstructorHandling = ConstructorHandling.AllowNonPublicDefaultConstructor,
            TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All
        };
        var stream = new MemoryStream(objectData) { Position = 0 };
        using (var reader = new BsonReader(stream))
        {
            return serializer.Deserialize<LargeObject>(reader);
        }
    }
```